# How to find out if ls command output is file or a directory Bash

Tags: linux, bash

ls command outputs everything that is contained in current directory. For example ls -la will output something like this

```
drwxr-xr-x  3   user  user  4096  dec  19  17:53  .
drwxr-xr-x 15   user  user  4096  dec  19  17:39  ..
drwxrwxr-x  2   user  user  4096  dec  19  17:53  tess  (directory)
-rw-r--r--  1   user  user   178  dec  18  21:52  file  (file)
-rw-r--r--  1   user  user    30  dec  18  21:47  text  (file)
```

And what if I want to know how much space does all files consume. For that I would have to sum $5 from all lines with `ls -la | awk '{ sum+=$5 } END{print sum}'`. So how can I only sum size of files and leave directories behind?

Comment: To sum file sizes you would use the tool `du` (disk usage). See `man du` or `du --help`. BTW, directories are marked with `d` in the permission block `$1` of `ls -l`, eg. `drwxr-xr-x` is a directory, `-rwxr-xr-x` is not a directory.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Please, allow us to Google that for you: [ls output file or directory](https://www.google.com/search?q=ls%2Boutput%2Bfile%2Bor%2Bdirectory). The first answer is [Determine if ls output is file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348962/56041) on U&L Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

The `find` command selects all the files in the current directory and output their size. The `awk` command sums the integers and output the total.

Comment: Might also want `-maxdepth 1`; I don't believe the OP wants to recurse (they're pretty explicit about "in the current directory", and of course their `ls` didn't have a `-R`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, thank you for your assistance !

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

One of the most quoted pages on SO that I've seen is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead.

That being said and as a hint for further development, `ls -l | awk '/^-/{s+=$5} END {print s}'` will probably do what you ask.